# Like button aren't connecting to Facebook Feed after DNS change with website re-design

Tags: dns, facebook-like

So I just launched a re-designed website on a new server.  It's been 48 hours since the site migration from the old server to the new server.  I just added Like buttons to news entries and for some reason they're not showing up on a users wall when clicked on.  If a comment is entered in the drop down (after clicking Like) and the Post to Facebook button is clicked, then the comment shows with a URL to the page--no title, no description text, etc.  The only thing I can think is that Facebook for some reason has the old website DNS cached which of course would lead to unavailable URLs.

Anybody experienced this?  Normally Like buttons are super simple to implement, but these one are being stubborn.

Answer (score 0):

Either Facebook DNS hasn't propagated or their cache is old.

You can clear FB's cache by putting in your url in here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: That's what I thought the deal was, just didn't know about that debug tool.  Thanks for the heads up!  It's cooking now.